# jQuery Nav Issue

Tags: jquery

I currently have a drop-style navigation structure built and working. I am trying to expand the navigation by adding the following elements:

Currently working:
1. When hovering over an "li" link a div container adjacent to list shows content related to the link.
2. The "li" and child "div backgound color changes to the width of the container.
3. The container ".servBox" appears when hovering on the link / div area.

Problem:
I would like to be able to hover over the "servBox" without it hiding.

Here is what I currently have....

http://jsfiddle.net/Robbo/mTNJf/

```
jQuery(".flyout").on('hover', function(){
var num = $(this).data('contentid');
jQuery('#serv-hover-' + num).toggle();
});

.megamenu .col_2,
.megamenu .col_3 {
float: left;
display:inline;
position: relative;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-right: 15px;
}
.megamenu .col_2 {width:149px}
.megamenu .col_3 {width:210px;}
.mm-level-1 ul {}
li.flyout { margin:0; padding: 0;display:block}
li.flyout > div:hover {background-color: #ff0000;margin-right:-100px;padding-right:50px;}

.servBox {
display: none;
top: -1px;
background: #ff0000;
min-height: 230px;
width: 230px;
}

<div class="megamenu">
<div class="col_2">
    <ul class="mm-level-1">
        <li class="flyout" data-contentid="as-1"><div><a href="#">Link 1</a></div></li>
        <li class="flyout" data-contentid="as-2"><div><a href="#">Link 2</a></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col_3">
    <div id="serv-hover-as-1" class="servBox" style="display:none;">Content 1</div>
    <div id="serv-hover-as-2" class="servBox" style="display:none;">Content 2</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this

**jQuery**

```
$(".flyout").hover(
                function(){
                    var num = $(this).data('contentid');
                    $('#serv-hover-' + num).show();
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                },
                 function(){
                     /*on moiuseleave, do nothing*/
                 });
$(".servBox").hover(
                function(){
                     /*on moiuseenter, do nothing*/
                },
                 function(){
                    $(this).hide();
                     $(".flyout").removeClass("active");
                 });
```

**Additional CSS**

```
li.active,
li.flyout > div:hover {
   background-color: #ff0000;
   margin-right:-100px;
   padding-right:50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/rn6e5/

**Edit**

You could make a function to deactivate the servBoxes and call it anytime - for example, before you set the active state in the hover function.

```
function hideServBox(){
    $(".servBox").hide();
    $(".flyout").removeClass("active");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/rn6e5/1/

**Additionally,**

To make mthe boxes disappear when the mouse goes off of the nav bar area as well, simply [run the `hideServBox` function on `.megamenu` hover's second function](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/rn6e5/2/). Or, combine them like so:

```
$(".servBox, .megamenu").mouseleave(
                function(){
                     hideServBox();
                 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/rn6e5/3/

Comment: That's it. I only find one problem, when the mouse hovers between links the servBox container doesn't hide when leaving the first link and the servBox shows data from both. Any ideas how to correct the behavior?  http://jsfiddle.net/Robbo/MEksb/

Comment: Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/rn6e5/1/ (also edited my answer to reflect the update)

Comment: Douglas, How do I make it that upon mouse exit the <div> element both the "servBox" and div backgroud are hidden?

Comment: @Robert Just run the function again on mouse leave. I updated my code accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following  code:

```
    jQuery(".flyout").on('hover', function(){
var num = $(this).data('contentid');
jQuery(".servBox").hide();
jQuery('#serv-hover-' + num).show();
```

});

This is just a quick fix. There might be better approaches as well.